# Display column using div dynamically having first column fixed and rest of all with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, angular5

I need your help.

I am creating an N-level nested table with dynamic columns

So what I want to do is, I want to create a table having a variable number of columns based on user selection for that I have created a simple drop-down box, according to drop-down selection, those selected columns will appear in the table

What I want is my first column of the table should be always fixed and while others can be scroll-able horizontally, and the width of those columns should be adjusted as column displays or hides

I don't want to use any external libraries. I have created a custom table based on div along with grid CSS

Below are screenshots of things that I have done till now

[image]

Here is code for reference:

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let rData of reportData; let i = index; last as isLast" >
  <div class="myTr report-row">
    <div class="myTd">
        <button 
           class="btn report-btn-sm" 
           *ngIf="checkIfHaveMoreSplits(this.splitOpt[0].id) !== 0 && rData.isCollapsed == true"
           (click)="splitData(rowWiseFilterObj(rData,this.splitOpt[0].id),this.splitOpt[0].id,sFilters,splitOpt,i,rData,selectedDate)"
           row="rData">+</button>
        <button 
           class="btn report-btn-sm" 
           *ngIf="checkIfHaveMoreSplits(this.splitOpt[0].id) !== 0 && rData.isCollapsed == false" 
           (click)="removeDynamicComponent(rData,i)"
           >-</button>
           <span *ngIf="this.splitOpt[0].id == 'campid'">{{rData['campaign_name']}}</span>

          <span *ngIf="this.splitOpt[0].id !== '__time' && this.splitOpt[0].id !== 'campid'">{{rData[this.splitOpt[0].id]}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="this.splitOpt[0].id === '__time'">{{ rData[this.splitOpt[0].id]  | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span>


    </div>
    <div class="myTdGroupBox"><div class="myTdGroup">
      <div class="myTd">{{convertToDecimals(rData.impressions,2)}}</div>
      <div class="myTd">{{convertToDecimals(rData.conversions,2)}}</div>
      <div class="myTd">{{convertToDecimals(rData.bids,2)}}</div>
      <div class="myTd">{{convertToDecimals(rData.wins,2)}}</div>
      <div class="myTd">$ {{convertToDecimals(rData.spend,2)}}</div>
      <div class="myTd">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--label-danger m-btn--label-danger m-btn--bolder m-btn--uppercase btn-sm" *ngIf="this.splitOpt[0].id=='campid'" (click)="excludeReport(rowWiseFilterObj(rData,this.splitOpt[0].id))"> <i class="la la-close"></i> </button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--label-danger m-btn--bolder m-btn--uppercase btn-sm" disabled="disabled" *ngIf="this.splitOpt[0].id!='campid'"> <i class="la la-ban"></i> </button>

      </div>
    </div></div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="isLast" class="text-right col-12">{{altrows("#ffffff","#f5f5f5")}}

            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="m-link" (click)="loadmore()" style="    margin: 10px -30px 15px 10px;
    background: #5ccdde;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;" *ngIf="reportData.length > 19"> Load more </a>
        </div>
    <ng-template #dynamic ></ng-template>

    </ng-container>
  <div class="myTr" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="myTd"></div>
    <div class="myTdGroupBox"><div class="myTdGroup">
      <div class="myTd"></div>
    </div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
getReport() {
        this.hidePopup();
        if(this.splitOpt.length === 0) {
            // this.updateGraph(this.currentGraphSelection);
            return false;
        } 


        var apiFilters: any = [{}];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.sFilters.length; i++) {
            if (this.sFilters[i].values.length > 0) {
                var k;
                k = this.sFilters[i].id
                apiFilters[0][k] = this.sFilters[i].values
            }
        }

        var split = this.splitOpt[0].id;
        this.reportData=[];
        this.reportLoading = true;
        this._apis.getReportData(split, apiFilters[0],this.selectedDate,1,20).subscribe(response => {
            if (response.status == 1200) {
                this.reportData = response.data.split_by_data;
                this.reportData.map(function(obj) {
                  obj.isCollapsed = true;
                  return obj;
               });
            this.totalImpressions=response.data.totalCount[0].impressions;
            this.totalConversions=response.data.totalCount[0].conversions;
            this.totalBids=response.data.totalCount[0].bids;
            this.totalWins=response.data.totalCount[0].wins;
            this.totalSpend=response.data.totalCount[0].spend;
               this.reportLoading = false;
               var contentGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.myTr:not(:last-child) .myTdGroupBox');
var ctrlGroup = document.querySelector('.myTr:last-child .myTdGroupBox');
ctrlGroup.addEventListener('scroll', (ev)=> {
    contentGroups.forEach((g)=> g.scrollTo(ctrlGroup.scrollLeft, 0) );
});
               this.cd.detectChanges();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You cannot have part of a table overflow only. You'd need to carefully draw two tables alongside each other inside a div. One div is fixed width, the other alongside it can then overflow.

Comment: I guess it is possible i have seen this thing in datatables library
I am aware of solutions that you are suggesting !
Also there are so many nested tables that are inserted using dynamic components.
In my case this solution won't help much

Comment: The layout is quiet complicated here, but thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remake the table using `<div>`s with flex layout.

I write a full example below. You don't have all flexibility of a table, however it's quite powerful. You can also fix the columns scroller to the page, and make it ever visible, even with a table bigger than the page height. And more...

You'll see, i make the scrollable columns all with the same width. You can set different widths. I would do this using classes for columns.

I believe the code is easy to understand. If you need a help, or want to use more of the power of flex layout, you can see this page: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The javascript to make all move together is the most simple thing here. The idea is to get the scroll event and apply the same scroll tho the lines with `overflow: hidden`.

To create new columns, is as simple as create it on a `<table>`, just crate `<div>`s into `.myTdGroup` elements.

```html
<style>
  .myTable {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 450px;
    border: 2px solid #BBB;
    position: relative;
  }
  .myTr {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .myTr:nth-child(odd) { background: #DDD }
  .myTdGroupBox {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .myTdGroup {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 500px;
  }
  .myTr:last-child { background: #777 }
  .myTr:last-child .myTdGroupBox { overflow-x: scroll }
  .myTr:last-child .myTd { padding: .1px 0 0 0 }
  .myTd {
    margin: 0 1em;
    padding: .5em 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 50px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .myTr > .myTd { flex-basis: 150px; }
</style>

<div class="myTable">
  <div class="myTr">
    <div class="myTd">Line A</div>
    <div class="myTdGroupBox"><div class="myTdGroup">
      <div class="myTd">A1</div>
      <div class="myTd">A222</div>
      <div class="myTd">A333</div>
      <div class="myTd">A444</div>
      <div class="myTd">A555</div>
      <div class="myTd">A666</div>
    </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="myTr">
    <div class="myTd">Line BBBBB</div>
    <div class="myTdGroupBox"><div class="myTdGroup">
      <div class="myTd">B111</div>
      <div class="myTd">B2</div>
      <div class="myTd">B333</div>
      <div class="myTd">BX<br>444</div>
      <div class="myTd">B555</div>
      <div class="myTd">B666</div>
    </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="myTr">
    <div class="myTd">Line<br>CCC<br>CCC</div>
    <div class="myTdGroupBox"><div class="myTdGroup">
      <div class="myTd">C111</div>
      <div class="myTd">C222</div>
      <div class="myTd">C3</div>
      <div class="myTd">C 444 444 444 end</div>
      <div class="myTd">C555</div>
      <div class="myTd">C666</div>
    </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="myTr">
    <div class="myTd">Line DDD</div>
    <div class="myTdGroupBox"><div class="myTdGroup">
      <div class="myTd">D111</div>
      <div class="myTd">D222</div>
      <div class="myTd">D333</div>
      <div class="myTd">D444</div>
      <div class="myTd">D555</div>
      <div class="myTd">D666</div>
    </div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="myTr">
    <div class="myTd"></div>
    <div class="myTdGroupBox"><div class="myTdGroup">
      <div class="myTd"></div>
    </div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var contentGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.myTr:not(:last-child) .myTdGroupBox');
var ctrlGroup = document.querySelector('.myTr:last-child .myTdGroupBox');
ctrlGroup.addEventListener('scroll', (ev)=> {
    contentGroups.forEach((g)=> g.scrollTo(ctrlGroup.scrollLeft, 0) );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi
Yes i tried your solution 
I kept this javascript thing on ngAfterviewInit
But it is not working on dynamic rows

Comment: i also tried by keeping js code after my ajax request still not working! may be something needs to done with angular 5?

Comment: I have added code to question 
Have look at it
Right now solution is working but only first static row is scrollable not the results retrieved from backend

Comment: I also tried to implement using static array its working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7z3pa

Check here dont know whats wrong with ajax requests

Comment: I also tried to execute function whenever last row is rendered but still not working

Comment: One more little help if you have time
I would like to add vertical scroll bar as well because if there are more that 50 records lets say user have to go end of the page to scroll page

Comment: Here is my fiddle as i mentioned i have converted entire layout in div
Check out my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q309svn5/

Comment: Hi, If you add new rows dynamically, you must update the `contentGroups` array.

Comment: You can fix `.myTr:last-child` to have a visible horizontal scroll in a long table. How to fix? You must see what technique is better in your layout. `position:absolute` may work.

Answer (score 1):

Janak Prajapati, Earlier I have done something similar to fixed table.

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/2o4h6u3f/10/

```css
  

.tg {
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-spacing:0;
     border-color:#ccc;
}
 .tg td{
     font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size:14px;
     padding:9px 20px;
     border-style:solid;
     border-width:1px;
     overflow:hidden;
     word-break:normal;
     border-color:#ccc;
     color:#333;
     background-color:#fff;
}
 .tg th{
     font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size:14px;
     font-weight:normal;
     padding:9px 20px;
     border-style:solid;
     border-width:1px;
     overflow:hidden;
     word-break:normal;
     border-color:#ccc;
     color:#333;
     background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
 .tg .tg-29qf{
     font-weight:bold;
     background-color:#f0f0f0;
     border-color:inherit;
     text-align:left
}
 .tg .tg-xldj{
     border-color:inherit;
     text-align:left
}
 .tg .sticky-col-1{
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: auto;
     width: 120px;
}
 .tg .sticky-col-2{
     left: 160px;
     position: absolute;
     top: auto;
     width: 70px;
}
 .zui-scroller {
     margin-left: 295px;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y: visible;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
     width: 900px;
}
 .tg .tg-kiyi{
     font-weight:bold;
     border-color:inherit;
     text-align:left;
     min-width:100px;
}
 .tg .cover-head-cell{
     min-width:300px;
     text-align:center;
}
 .tg .tg-29qf{
     font-weight:bold;
     background-color:#f0f0f0;
     border-color:inherit;
     text-align:left;
     min-width:100px;
}
 .tg .tg-xldj{
     border-color:inherit;
     text-align:left;
     min-width:100px;
}
 .tg .tg-dvid{
     font-weight:bold;
     background-color:#efefef;
     border-color:inherit;
     text-align:left;
     vertical-align:top;
     min-width:100px;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .tg {
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .tg col {
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .tg-wrap {
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
```

```html
   

 <div class="tg-wrap">
       <div class="zui-scroller">
          <table class="tg">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi sticky-col-1" rowspan="2">Title 1</th>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi sticky-col-2" rowspan="2">Title 2</th>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi cover-head-cell" colspan="3">Title 3</th>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi" rowspan="2">Title 4</th>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi cover-head-cell" colspan="3">Title 5</th>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi" rowspan="2">Title 6</th>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi cover-head-cell" colspan="3">Title 7</th>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi" rowspan="2">Title 8</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi sticky-col-1" rowspan="2">Subtitle 1</th>
                   <th class="tg-kiyi sticky-col-2" rowspan="2">Subtitle 2</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 3</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 4</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 5</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 6</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 7</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 8</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 9</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 10</th>
                   <th class="tg-29qf">Subtitle 11</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tr>
                <td class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1">sdz</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj sticky-col-2">saz</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">sa</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="tg-xldj sticky-col-1">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj sticky-col-2">sa</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">sa</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">as</td>
                <td class="tg-xldj">sa</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="tg-dvid sticky-col-1">Total</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid sticky-col-2">23</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">sd</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">ds</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">sd</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">sd</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">ds</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">dd</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">sd</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">ds</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">sd</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">ds</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">dd</td>
                <td class="tg-dvid">sd</td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Please try this and let me know your idea.
Thanks.

Comment: looks good for me ! i would not like to use table tags here
I want to create a table totally based on div. as i have n level of nested tables and inserting one table into another does not sound good to me

Comment: Yes it worked ! but if i have so many records i have to go end of the page to scroll horizontally. Is it possible to include vertical scroll bar as well
I have converted entire table based layout to div based on using css  display properties of css.
I will update it as well in answer 
If you can help me with vertical scroll bar it ll be great 

Many thanks for your help

Comment: @JanakPrajapati, I have upadated my JSFIDDLE link. Could check and let me know, is that you expecting from me?
https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/2o4h6u3f/25/

Comment: yes but again position fixed will always show when page scrolls ?
isn't it ?
I tried it before but i have graph above table when i scroll page that table will stay there as position is fixed.

Comment: @JanakPrajapati, Could you send me a working fiddle or anything ?

Comment: I tried one more solution ! i wrapped elements above this table with z-index 2 and gave z-index 1 to table it worked but again position fixed refers body height my top is lets say 70% so i can use remaining 30% height only
Not desired one

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/vjg0a7o8/
neglect css styling it is working fine in my system @VSM

Comment: And another one if i try this solution by fixing position of tg-wrap div
https://jsfiddle.net/0treh87n/
Here i have added black div and and gave necessary top and height to table if you see table's height is not what it actually should have

Comment: You there mate? @vsm